# Problema no dashboard do Magento

Tags: magento

Olá, eu acabei de instalar o Magento e ao instalar percebi que na dashboard ele não está funcionando muito bem, parece que o css de algumas coisas não está funcionando, e nem os menus dropdown, o

segue imagem: [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Verifique o que esta aparecendo no console do Chrome para identificar porque não carregou os CSS

Answer (score 1):

Aparentemente o local de acesso dos arquivos magento estão inacessíveis, tente utilizar "localhost" ao invés de "127.0.0.1" e tente trabalhar com a porta padrão (80) ao invés da 8080, isso também pode ser erro de permissão dos arquivos.

Clique com o botão direito do mouse sobre o primeiro ícone com erro na parte superior esquerda e escolha "abrir imagem em uma nova guia ou aba", caso retorne arquivo inacessível ou erro 404 significa que realmente o diretório de arquivos está no local errado ou inacessível, com isso, será necessário revisar as permissões e o local de seus arquivos magento e o caminho necessário para acessa-los.